# Google Play Games Services: List achievements of other player

Tags: java, google-play-games

I'm accessing the Google Play Games Services API from plain Java:

`games.achievements().list(playerId).execute()`

I seem to get only the current user's achievements - for other players, no result is returned.

The game is not yet published though, may that be the problem?
The [API docs](https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/achievements/list) says

> Lists the progress for all your application's achievements for the **currently authenticated** player."

But what's the point of providing a `playerId` then? Also, in the Play Games Android app, it is possible to compare one's achievements to so *does* seem possible.

Any experience? I don't know where to go with such contradicting information. I can't just publish in order to find out, nor can I continue without knowing if it'll work.

Comment: You don't need to publish the game provided the player is listed as a tester for your game in the Play Console.

Comment: It seems not to work either way.